# jRating plugin stars do not load at all

Tags: jquery, rating

i am using jRating plugin. Everything works fine, thing is... the images of the star does not appear despite the fact that my url to the images are correct and i have already tested with other similar image content that works well using the same conventional url such as "images/stars.png"

When i mouse over the url using firebug under style, the rest of my other contents' images appear but only the star.png will keep loading and does not appear.

anyone knows what is wrong? the image below is a sample of what i am referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: this module is rarely updated. You probably want to use Fivestar instead.**
http://drupal.org/project/fivestar

Comment: drupal seems complicated and it conflicts with jquery